# Redis: why MOVED to another master

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I've a Redis cluster - 3 masters and 3 slaves. This cluster contains ~300 keys(foo0 - foo300). I understand that each master responsible for certain subset of data and can redirect client to right node with MOVED error.

But, If I send request to GET **nonexisting** keys(like **klsdkaso**, **qwerty123** ...)  from master, I also got MOVED to another node. I'm confused. Who can explain why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key, whether it actually exists or not, is mapped by hashing its name (or parts of it, a.k.a tags) to a slot. Slots are assigned to masters, and a master first checks for a key's "belongingness" to it (in terms of the current slot ranges assignments) and only then performs any other operations.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make it clear, let's define two kinds of master nodes:

1. **Connected Node**: The node that your client connecting to, and you are sending `GET` command to this node.
2. **Destination Node**: The node that the given key **SHOULD** be located, i.e. the one you are redirected or moved to.

Because the **Connected Node** only has the slot-mapping information, i.e. the given key **SHOULD** be located on the **Destination Node**. However, it **DOES NOT** know whether the given key exists on **Destination Node**.

So the **Connected Node** has to redirect the client to the **Destination Node** first, i.e. use the `MOVED` error message to give the IP and port information on the **Destination Node**. Then the client sends another `GET` command to the **Destination Node** to check whether the given key really exists.